# Inside a MySQL trigger, how to know the calling script/program name?

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

The prices of real estates in a customer database have been changed two times in a month (with wrong prices), and I don't know from which user and which php script or program.

The server is under Debian 7 with MySQL 5.5 and PHP 5.6.

1) Inside a MySQL trigger (when a record is updated), how to know the calling (PHP) script/program name ?

2) I know I can execute a shell script inside a MySQL trigger, maybe I can use this possibility to know which script / program is doing the modification of the database/record. Is there a way in Linux to know which script / program is updating the mysql databases at the instant ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why don't you log this in the actual PHP-code? I assume you need to be logged in to edit / change the info, which should make it fairly easy to log who is doing changes to the database.

Comment: Because I don't know which PHP script is used, and maybe it's done in phpmyadmin or other means, because unfortunately I had to give FTP (with ability to run php code), Mysql and phpmyadmin access to 2 extern developpers.

Comment: I don't think there's any way for the MySQL server to know anything about the script that's making the queries. Not just triggers, but any query.

Comment: Then you will have to turn on logging in all apps (PHPMyAdmin, MySQL), for all changes. Which is gonna be taxing for the server, to say the least. Why did you need to give them access to live data? That is just bad practice, in so many ways. Set them up on a dev-server, not the live one. Only things that goes to the live one is verified updates / patches. No need to change anything in the DB directly, only via admin-interface on the site - at least in production.

Comment: Thank you Barmar. Thank you junkfoodjunkie. I think seriously about removing them the access. I enabled all the logs, but I found the culprit ! It was GoogleBot which has read/opened an old .php file which converts Francs to Euros. Thank you again.